# Trying to set header ContentDisposition on PutObjectCommand results in a 403 forbidden

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I upload files to S3 successfully with my application. I do a direct upload from the browser using a signedUrl that my server generates for me using the aws-sdk v3.

To get the singed URL it looks a bit like this

```
const s3Params = {
        Bucket : bucketName,
        Key : fileName,
        ContentType:fileType,
        // Metadata:{'Content-Disposition':'attachment'}
        // ContentDisposition:'attachment'
    };


    try {
        const command = new PutObjectCommand(s3Params);

        const url = await getSignedUrl(s3v3,command,{expiresIn:60});
        return url;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('************** there was an error signing th url');
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

This is working perfectly fine, but then as i read a bit of the documentation I saw that i should be able to set the header ContentDisposition. In [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/putobjectcommandinput.html) it says that the input of PutObjectCommand extends from the [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/putobjectrequest.html)

The latter has an optional parameter called `ContentDisposition` as i would like to set this to attachment, to allow me to prompt a "download" window for my users. However, when I use the signedURL as above but add the `ContentDisposition:'attachment'` field i get a Forbidden Error.

Does anyone know if im missing anything here? is this not an actual option or do i need to modify something in my permissions of S3 for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to specify the `ContentDisposition` for the `PutObjectCommand` param and also for the `getSignedUrl` function as such:

```
async function main(fileName, bucketName, fileType) {
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        ContentType: fileType,
        ContentDisposition: 'attachment'
    };

    const client = new S3Client({region: 'us-east-1'});
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(s3Params);

    const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, {expiresIn: 60, ContentDisposition: 'attachment'});

    const file = await fs.readFile(fileName);

    const result = await axios({
        method: 'put',
        url,
        data: file,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': fileType,
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```